# How to generate HTML Test Report with Test Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testunit

I have a simple project to develop in test::unit framework, which is working fine. I want to generate an HTML test report of the tests I executed with passed/failed status and other relative data.

I have three files:

Rakefile (to call runner.rb file):

```
task :default => :TestRunner
    desc "run suite test"
    task :TestRunner  do
      ruby "D:/TestUnit/runner.rb"
    end
```

runner.rb (to execute test suite):

```
base_dir = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ".."))
test_dir = File.join(base_dir, "testUnit/suite.rb")

require 'test/unit'

exit Test::Unit::AutoRunner.run(true, test_dir)
```

suite.rb (contains all the tests):

```
gem "test-unit"
require "test/unit"

class Test1< Test::Unit::TestCase
description "Test Case for adding two values..!!", :test_add
description "Test Case for subtracting two values..!!", :test_sub

  def setup
  puts "running the setup........."
    @number1 = 4
  @number2 = 2  
  end
  def test_add
  puts "asserting the add function: " + description
  numb1=@number1+@number2
    assert_equal(7, numb1 + 1, "added correctly")
  end

  def test_sub
  puts "asserting the subtract function: " + description
  numb2=@number1-@number2   
    assert_equal(2, numb2 - 0, "subtracted correctly")
  end

  def teardown
  puts "running teardown......."
    @number = nil   
  end
end
```

What else do I need to do to generate an HTML test report?